# choose ZigBee modules for full wireless mesh

Tags: mobile-robot, microcontroller, radio-control, communication, wireless

What is the most common **ZigBee IP Modules** to create **full wireless mesh** mode? 
I know that it should be *1) coordinator and 2) router* to **create full-mesh**

But I am interesting about what kind of modules it would be better to buy by **comparing price, quality and tutorial material.** It would be graet if you know some ZigBee modules based on ARM(Cortex) or Atmel MCUs and if you have some additional **tutorial materials to control those modules** and  understand it.

I am looking for ZigBee modules only, but *NOT XBee*!!!
because they have difference in organization of network. 
Ex.: 
***First of all,*** ZigBee Mesh can create own zones to control devices. 
but in *Xbee Mesh* which from Digi Comany can create only full mesh and only one big or huge zone to control devices.

**Secondly,** *ZigBee* modules - AES encryption. Can lock down network and prevent other nodes from joining.
*Xbee* - AES encryption.** and it is coming soon...

Comment: Any answer to this question is opinion based. In Stack Exchange sites, we try to maintain questions that can be answered with scientific facts. You may get lucky if you get a good answer, but the question as it stands doesn't invite an answer more than "buy XYZ, I used it once, it was fine". Besides, shopping questions can get outdated really fast. Some brand XYZ may be the best now, but a terrible choice a year from now.

Comment: A better question would be to 1) indicate what you are trying to achieve. 2) Tell us what you think should be requirements for the ZigBee module (so we know you made an effort, and to avoid telling what you already know, and to correct you if you are mistaken). 3) Ask what the more experienced users here think should be the requirements for the ZigBee module. Once you get answers, browse through ZigBee modules of different brands, look at their datasheets and see for yourself which one matches best those requirements.

Comment: Almost seven later, this question has not drawn any answers, and shows that shopping questions do not stand the test of time. I voted that it be closed.